# Constant Expression Required in c Program

Tags: c, windows, for-loop, conditional-operator

The below code shows the error, "Constant Expression Required." I tried some solutions but still I was unable to solve.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<conio.h>

int coins( int S[], int m, int n ) {
   int i, j, x, y;
   int table[n+1][m];
   for (i=0; i<m; i++)
      table[0][i] = 1;
   for (i = 1; i < n+1; i++) {
      for (j = 0; j < m; j++) {
         x = (i-S[j] >= 0)? table[i - S[j]][j]: 0;
         y = (j >= 1)? table[i][j-1]: 0;
         table[i][j] = x + y;
      }
   }
   return table[n][m-1];
}

int main() {
   int arr[20],n;
   int m,i;
   printf("********* MAKING CHANGE PROBLEM *********");
   printf("\nEnter size of array:");
   scanf("%d",&n);
   for(i=0;i<n;i++){
       scanf("%d",arr[i]);
   }
   m = sizeof(arr)/sizeof(arr[0]);
   printf("The total number of combinations of coins that sum up to %d",n);
   printf(" is %d ", coins(arr, m, n));
   getch();
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: you should copy the error message and the line it refers to, don't expect people to try and replicate your code to figure out where the error is.

Comment: You didn't show the exact and full error msg which should point to the line number. So at a guess it's this line: `int table[n+1][m];` Windows compilers do not support Variable Length Arrays (VLAs). Use `malloc` instead.

Comment: `scanf("%d",arr[i]);` that is also wrong. Should be `scanf("%d",&arr[i]);`. The compiler should give a warning for that.

Comment: What happens when you enter `n > 20`? You should follow through the `malloc` suggestion, after `n` has been entered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the different versions of C Language standard, following is not allowed, mostly the error is arising from here

```
int table[n+1][m];
```

instead use `#define NSIZE 10` and `#define MSIZE 20` and `int table[NSIZE+1][MSIZE];`etc

and `scanf("%d",arr[i]);` will cause problems use `scanf("%d",&arr[i]);`